# Having difficulty getting phpmailer to work to send an email with an attachment on submission of an html upload form

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

Morning all

I am adding a simple CV file upload form feature to a landing page I built a while back. I want it so that when the form is submitted, the contents, including the uploaded file (in any format) are sent in an email to a chosen email address. As it stands, I have downloaded composer and used it to install PHPMailer. I have the composer.lock, composer.json (which has the require phpmailer code block), and composer.phar files in my root directory for the project.

So far when I do submit the upload form, I get a blank page. I am not even presented with the echo "error" that I ask it to show me if there was a problem sending the mail. What is supposed to happen is the form is filled, file is uploaded and submitted. Then a thank you page should appear thanking the user for uploading their cv, and of course the email appears in the inbox with all the info and the attachment.

Here is the code for the upload form -

```
<section id="upload">
    <div>
      <h2>Upload your CV:</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="uploadText">
      <form action="toemail.php" method="POST" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="name" id="labelName">Name:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="fullName" id="name" required>
        <select id="typeofjob" name="jobpreference" required>
          <option value="choose" selected disabled>--Choose Area of Expertise--</option>
          <option value="Front of house">Front of House</option>
          <option value="Back of house">Back of House</option>
        </select>
        <input type="file" id="filetoupload" name="file" required>
        <button type="submit" name="upload_button" id="uploadbtn">Upload CV</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
```

and here is what I have for the php code. This is my first time using phpmailer so could be something I have overlooked. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php

// using Composer to dounwload PHP Mailer and PHP Mailer to attach the uploaded file to a sent email

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


    if(isset($_POST['upload_button'])){

        require 'phpmailer/phpmailerAutoload.php';
        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $name = $_POST['fullName'];
        $preference = $_POST['jobpreference'];
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
// $destination = 'uploads/'. $filename;
// $extension = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Your Domain Name
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Username = "____@gmaill.com"; // Your Email ID
        $mail->Password = "___"; // Password of your email id

        $mail->setFrom = "noreply@yourdomain.com";
        $mail->FromName = "___";
        $mail->AddAddress ("___"); // On which email id you want to get the message

        $mail->addAttachment($file,$filename); //This line Use to Keep User Txt,Doc,pdf file ,attachment

        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "Uploaded CV by $name"; // This is your subject

        // HTML Message Starts here

        $mail->Body = "
        <html>
            <body>
                <table style='width:600px;'>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='width:150px'><strong>Name: </strong></td>
                            <td style='width:400px'>$name</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style='width:150px'><strong>Email ID: </strong></td>
                            <td style='width:400px'>$preference</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
        ";
        // HTML Message Ends here


        if(!$mail->send())
            {
            echo "Error";
            }
        else
            {
                header('location:thanksforcv.html');
            }

}

?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A blank page typically means a fatal PHP error, so you should check your web server's error log for more details. It's most likely you have a problem with this line:

```
require 'phpmailer/phpmailerAutoload.php';
```

This file has not been present in PHPMailer for the last 3 years, so this will result in a fatal error; it's probably a result of copy & pasting old code from here on Stack Overflow. If you're in any doubt about whether code is correct, *always* get your advice directly from [the source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Hi @synchro. I checked the error logs. Turns out your right - PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in /home/wb1g0hb6a2yp/public_html/developersandbox.de/toemail.php on line 18 - as you said fatal php error. It seems it cannot find the vendor/autoload.php. Which is odd as it is there and in the right place. Am i missing something with where is should be positioned and how it should be called on?

Comment: and thank you for pointing out the importance of using direct source material and documentation. I have since changed the code to reflect that. Now the error logs are the focus.

Comment: Check that your relative path is correct – from the error message you just posted, it should be in `/home/wb1g0hb6a2yp/public_html/developersandbox.de/vendor`. Note that the PHPMailer examples are in a subfolder, so they use `../vendor`, which may not match your setup.

Comment: Checked and there was one letter off and so clearly would not find the file. Fould is found now. There are no error logs when i run it now and the redirect page loads indicating the email was sent. However I still do not receive the email. I will dig into this and post back here. @synchro

Comment: Set `SMTDebug = 2` and watch the output to confirm delivery, and check your spam folder. Gmail’s spam filtering is terrible, and legitimate emails often end up in there.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with using gmail or the fact that I'm hosting on go daddy. Looking into the phpmailer documentation for examples or troubleshooting for using smtp.gmail.com and go daddy. - seen quite a few posts on here about it, some of which you have either started on commented on **Synchro**

Comment: latest error log - 2020-06-17 05:59:40 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)

Comment: "Connection refused" is exactly what you would expect to see if you're trying to connect to gmail's SMTP server from GoDaddy, just as the PHPMailer documentation says. GoDaddy blocks outbound external SMTP; you *must* use GoDaddy's mail servers. This implies that you can't use a gmail.com from address either.

Comment: Yeah, lesson learnt about documentation coming first. There is still something missing it seems. Im using the GD mail servers and the email address set up through them. I will work through the php mailer documentation and examples again on Github and work my way there. I will post back here any updates. Thanks for you help and time @Synchro much appreciated!